# How to record TestNG script from Taurus and convert to Jmx?

Tags: jmeter, taurus

I used TestNg for writing Script. Using Taurus it executed successfully. Now I used the proxy2jmx service for converting JMX . Here I received an error/ warning --

```
 1. WARNING: There aren't requests recorded by proxy2jmx, check your proxy configuration 
2. WARNING: Problems with chrome tuning are encountered, take look at http://gettaurus.org/docs/Proxy2JMX/ for help
```

In documentation one info provided- 1. don't hardcode the path to chromedriver.exe in your scripts
**Then how  chromedrver.exe path provide in my script?**
and I try to run Taurus on admin and recorded so it is wrong behavior or correct ?
and What is the solution for the above 2 warnings?
Some requests are recorded but when executed in Jmeter it cant work. It returns time out error .
So how all these issues are resolved?

### below is my yml file-

```
execution: 
  - 
    executor: testng
    iterations: 1
    scenario: scn1
modules: 
  blazemeter: 
    token: "707ab103114456ad7af656613827f:7e30d7ba25e396565656565656c53f1-e1cf413367c14c669a7c20d97fb567139fbb92d768d795b36e4d64"
  testng: 
    autodetect-xml: false
scenarios: 
  scn1: 
    script: TestAdminPage.java
services: 
  - 
    module: proxy2jmx
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Taurus looks for `chromedriver` binary in your operating system [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable))
2. Looking at `There aren't requests recorded by proxy2jmx` message I don't think that anything has been recorded at all
3. We cannot help you without seeing the full `bzt.log` file (lives in Taurus [Artifacts Directory](https://gettaurus.org/docs/ArtifactsDir/))
4. I don't think that [Proxy2JMX module](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-convert-selenium-scripts-jmx-converter) supports anything but JUnit,